# GitLab sidekiq failing test

Tags: rubygems, rake, gitlab

I am following the instructions here:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4-1-stable/doc/install/databases.md

When I try to run the tests:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

The first test returns orange headers, the second test shows an error with Sidekiq:

```
Checking Sidekiq ...    

Running? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake sidekiq:start
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  see log/sidekiq.log for possible errors
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Checking Sidekiq ... Finished
```

When I run `sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake sidekiq:start`, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rb-inotify
/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I run trace, I get the following output:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rb-inotify
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2     levels) in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I have already attempted to manually install `rb-inotify` to correct the issue:

```
sudo gem install rb-inotify
```

It says that it is successful, but the tests still do not work!  Please advise!  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That kind of command:

```
 sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake sidekiq:start
```

not only needs to be run in the gitlab cloned repo, but also need a `RAILS_ENV=production` to function properly:

```
 sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake sidekiq:start RAILS_ENV=production
```

See the **[troubleshooting page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide)**:

> - **`Error`**: `no such file to load -- rb-inotify` when running `rake` (as seen in [#1752](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1752))
> - **`Problem`**: task run in wrong environment
> - **`Solution`**: add `RAILS_ENV=production` to the end of the command

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I was running it the wrong way.  Running it this way solved it:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

The tutorial needs to be updated